# Adding a ReactJS front end to my REST API

Tags: java, rest, maven, reactjs, spring-boot

I am really new to front end development. I created a maven project and finished defining my REST API entry points using spring boot framework. I would like to add to the project a basic front end using reactJS. So I started with the basic html welcome. I added a war/WEB-inf/index.jsp welcome page:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Example</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>This is my test.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And a war/WEB-inf/web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" >

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>
      index.jsp
    </welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Trying to access the page by going to localhost:8080

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Jun 21 12:33:05 CEST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

I would appreciate some help

Comment: Why not decouple the frontend app from the backend? So on spring-boot you just code the rest services and on the frontend you consume those services. Webpack with weback-dev-server will help you with the serving the frontend when developping

Comment: @Sudakatux Is it a better practice to decouple them? How would they would they be deployed together for production? if yes can you provide me with a good tutorial in order to start developing reactJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to serve static content and you're using Spring boot, you can simply create an `index.html` file inside the  `src/main/resources/public` or `src/main/resources/static` directory. If you're only going to use React (or any other JavaScript framework), this setup should work. Just add all your JavaScript/CSS/HTML within this folder.

If you need a dynamic HTML page (using JSP/JSTL for example), you can add it to the `src/main/resources/templates` folder, but then you'll probably have to define a controller to use the `index.jsp` template file.

You don't need a Web descriptor (web.xml) either, so you can remove that.

Comment: It worked thanks. Would you help by providing me with a cool library for React JS components?

Comment: I have no idea, I'm not really experienced with React, but I'm pretty sure you cn google that.